# Not getting exact latitude longitude on ios device using watchPosition

Tags: react-native, geolocation, react-native-ios

**Issue Description::**

I am working on react native tracking application. Basically users check in from a certain place and they need to reach at the destination. Using this application we are finding out the path they are following. I need to get a geocodes from users check in location to destination to track the path he is following.
Now it builds a clean path in case of Android device, but having an issue with ios. For ios it takes a huge variation inside code.
I have tested this by traveling to same place using both devices(ios and android). For Android it's generates a exact latitude longitude values, but for ios there is a huge variation. Why this is happening. I have followed the official doc of react native for geolocation setup.
You can check this link:: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/geolocation.html#ios

We are using react native geolocation service package, [GitHub link](https://github.com/Agontuk/react-native-geolocation-service)

This is happening when I have updated react native version to 0.58

**Code::**

```
this.watchId = Geolocation.watchPosition((response) => {
    this.currentWatchLocationTimeout = this.currentWatchLocationTimeout + WATCH_LOCATION_TIMEOUT;

    currentPosition.lat = this.convertToDecimalPoints(response.coords.latitude);
    currentPosition.lng = this.convertToDecimalPoints(response.coords.longitude);

    //... additional code

}, (error) => {
    this.onGeolocationErrorOccurCallback(error);
}, {
    enableHighAccuracy: true,
    distanceFilter: 5,
    showLocationDialog: true
});
```

**Additional Information ::**

- React Native: 0.58
- react-native-geolocation-service: 2.0.0
- platform: ios(only)

Comment: What are the results if you use iOS simulator? You can also simulate a trip on your computer using xCode. If results are oké, it seems a hardware issue. What kind of device did you use? Did you try another iOS device?

Comment: I didn't check this on ios simulator but tested on different ios device and gives us a weird result every time.

Comment: It works when we have not updated react-native version to 0.58, I have no idea why this problem occurs now.

Comment: I find out a bug report issue inside react-native package, you can check this link:: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12967
I am not sure is it fixed inside react native 0.58 or not. Because I have tested it on multiple devices and it still gives us wrong latitude longitude values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best solution that works for me is changes inside react native geolocation files. You need to replace some lines of code. Go inside react native package,

> react-native/Libraries/Geolocation/RCTLocationObserver.m

Then replace this line::

```
#define RCT_DEFAULT_LOCATION_ACCURACY kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
```

with this::

```
#define RCT_DEFAULT_LOCATION_ACCURACY 0.0
```

After this replace this line::

```
.accuracy = [RCTConvert BOOL:options[@"enableHighAccuracy"]] ? kCLLocationAccuracyBest : RCT_DEFAULT_LOCATION_ACCURACY,
```

with this one::

```
.accuracy = RCT_DEFAULT_LOCATION_ACCURACY,
```

You need to directly search for these lines on above mentioned path.
I found this inside git commits, you can also check this link:: [link](https://github.com/reyalpsirc/react-native/commit/408d949ae35c2fd9ff8055022815913bd652bf1a)